# Time-slotted diagram generation tool

Tags: graphs

I know there is a diagram tool like Graphviz, that taking a script and outputs a graph-like diagram.

I am wondering if there is similar tool that can produce the time-slotted diagram like the following?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried searching for Gantt tools?

Answer (score 2):

There are several, much more general, plotting packages that can produce the sorts of plots you are talking about from a data file, *as well as many 100s of other layouts*:

- [GNUPlot](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/) - Gratis & Open Source, cross platform
- The [Python](https://www.python.org/) [MatPlotLib](http://matplotlib.org) - Gratis & Open Source, cross platform, *python can also be used to extract the data you wish to plot.*